# How to join two elements in a list that are separated by a space?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list whose elements came from a text file.

```
[griffin.keyes, 
108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f, 
"alphabet, soup", 
 zookeeper]
```

Here is the code to grab the the text and put it in a list:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("credentials.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        list.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
```

The problem is "alphabet soup", and other elements that have a space, are being interpreted as two elements. So

```
System.out.println(list.get(2)); == "alphabet
```

and

```
System.out.println(list.get(3)); == soup"
```

How do you tell the program to treat them as one element?

Edit:

I used the nextLine method, which worked. But now I have another problem: each line is being treated as an element (which yea that is what is supposed to happen). So I need to separate the text in each line. There is a lot of whitespace.

This is the first element now:

```
   [griffin.keyes       108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f        
   "alphabet soup"          zookeeper]
```

Now I need to separate those into different elements. I'm assuming I will use the split method. Now sure how to go about it, though.

Comment: Use `s.hasNextLine()` and `s.nextLine`

Comment: can you post the text file you use

Comment: You can also use `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("credentials.txt"))`

Comment: That worked. Now just need to get rid of all the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("credentials.txt")))
    {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            list.add(s.nextLine());
        }
    }
    for(String val:list)
        System.out.println(val);
}
```

See it working [here](https://ideone.com/tIiYwO). [*In this working example `System.in` is used instead of normal file due to some restriction.*]